# Can I use AdSense with a domain that contains trademarks?

Tags: seo, domains, google-adsense, legal, infringement

I just landed in the world of writing Blogs and doing the SEOs; I was looking to set up a nice blog having most target keywords and all other things. Luckily I was able to book a domain name having keywords 'Apple and iOS'.

Now, as I read more about it on the Internet, I can totally see that using the trademarks and name of the companies is illegal and might attract some infringement cases, and since I am looking forward to earning some money with it, Google just might not allow me to use the AdSense on that domain.

I paid like $12 for the domain, can I use the domain name with AdSense?

Comment: Your registrar should be able to help you given the circumstances. They should not have allowed you to register the domain name in the first place. If you talk to them politely, you should be able to register another domain name in place of the one you have now. Otherwise, you may be stuck. At least it was only $12. Not the end of the world.

Comment: Yeah, adding to what closetnoc has said, even if the registrar do not return your money in the form of another domain - do not use this domain for building anything worthwhile. Register another domain without trademarks and start investing your time there. Believe me, if you work hard $12 will not be even a drop (may be, just an atom or proton) in comparison to the amount of money you can make. Otherwise, you will just live in fear that someday 'apple' will take away all your hard work (rightfully).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I was wondering how Apple.Stackexchange.com is surviving without any issues?

Comment: The `Apple` in `Apple.Stackexchange.com` is a _subdomain_ that's neither registered, nor blocking any other party from using its trademark in a domain name. Using a trademark in a domain is not in itself infringement (there are lots of domains with the word `apple` in them). It's _how_ you use the domain that might be actionable and cause for a [UDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy), which may result in you losing your domain. `IOS` is not a trademark of Apple's by the way, it belongs to Cisco and is licensed...

Comment: You can view Apple's trademarked names [here](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html). If Apple feels you're trying to divert traffic away from their business by using their trademark in your domain name and site with related content, you might get a letter from their legal department. It's a risky proposition, but doesn't mean you can't use the domain name that you're the registrant of. I don't think AdSense will reject you based on the domain name, but might on the content if it's found to contain trademark infringements...

Comment: [Here](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6118?hl=en) is their policy on trademarks. In any case, it's not a great foundation for building a blog from though, and domains can be had for even cheaper (search for "$0.99 domains" for example). It's probably wiser to invest your time and effort into something less risky if you feel you're possibly going to be treading on Apple's territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Adsense,  but if the trademark owner complains to ICANN, you can have the name removed from your account without even a notice. If they complain to Google, Google may or may not remove / suspend the site from using Adsense.   So, you are better off just starting your site without other peoples trademarks.

Answer (score 1):

Google blocks AdSense requests if they feel the site may have misleading or fraud content or anything that isn't complying with their rules. 
*If you already have good track in case of traffic and genuine content. They will accept you.* 
**Trademarks won't be a problem with verification. Just a problem if the company thinks they should warn you.**